# Custom angular directive with isolated scope

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a simple page with shows the calender page.

What i have is a html fragment, which iterates over a days array and creates a cell for each day of the month.So i am going to pass the current day, current month,current year and weeks array to this template.

The logic worked fine when it used the global scope,but as one can have multiple calender instances within a page, i created a isolated scope and want to push the values to the fragment when the directive renders.

I am not able to bind the scope values with the html fragment .It keeps throwing me error:
`'Error: Non-assignable model expression: undefined (directive: calender)'` .

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/chinmay_sagade/63ZmZ/1/).

Need help in understanding what needs to be done inorder to get this thing working with isolated scope.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle? The fiddle has the code, but not in any testable context. If I can play with it, I can see what's wrong.

Comment: Hi Josh,Sry that the fiddle is not working. the fragment is a different file altogether and i wasn't sure how to make that functional.Let me see what i can do.

Comment: It's not immediately obvious, but you can use templates in jsFiddle like this: http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/NEuJ6/.

Comment: was able to figure out what was wrong.Replaced the scope attribute to:scope:{
            ngModel: '='
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting Error: Non-assignable model expression: undefined  error because there were no bindable attributes on my directive by that name,instead those were model values.
I replaced the scope defination to 
scope:{ngModel: '='} and the the linker function was then able to update the model values.

Comment: I am not sure it is wise to overwrite how an angular directive works. If you need something on the scope of the directive, with bi-directional binding, then the '=' approach is correct, but I would rename the attribute to something else to avoid confusion.